# Rails attachment url replace s3 with subdomain off app domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, subdomain, asset-pipeline

I have images that are currently being stored in Amazon s3 but I want the attachment url to go to a new subdomain off the rails domain instead of to s3. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

In your image model, write an method, do the domain replacement logic for url in that method.

suppose you have a `attachment_url`:

```
def attachment_url
  # implement the logic here
end
```

get the `@image` in controller, then you could use it like so

```
image_tag @image.attachment_url
```

Comment: can you provide an example? and then what would go in the "<img src=" field?

Comment: sorry, what would the attachment_url logic be? to be clear, I want the image to remain on s3, but I want the url in the DOM to be a subdomain of my rails app